# Error: Not null violation al llamar a una función dentro de otra

Tags: php

Me está dando error al llamar a una función dentro de otra. 
Trato de llamar a la función `an_serv` pasándole por referencia a `$fecha_i` y me da un error, la función `an_serv` es para calcular los años de servicio.

Éste es el error que recibo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: el valor null para la columna «fecha_i» viola la restricción not null DETAIL: La fila que falla contiene (null, 25623441, Alexander, Cortez, alex_barrios321@hotmail.com, Fijo). in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\CS\Models\EmployeeModels.php:135 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\CS\Models\EmployeeModels.php(135): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\CS\Controller\Controller.php(34): Fijo->Guardar() #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\CS\Models\EmployeeModels.php on line 135

Y éste es mi código:

```
class Fijo extends Empleado{

    //Atributos
    protected $s_m;
    protected $a_s;
    protected $p_a;
    protected $n_s; 

    //Metodo

    public function __construct($fecha_i = '', $estatus = '', $cedula = 1010, $nombre = '', $apellido = '', $correo = '', $s_m = 0){
            parent::__construct($fecha_i, $estatus , $cedula , $nombre , $apellido, $correo);

            $this->s_m = $s_m;
            $this->a_s = $this->an_serv($fecha_i );
            $this->p_a = 0;
            $this->n_s = 0;
            $this->p_a = $this->s_m * $this->a_s * 0.20;
            $this->n_s = $this->s_m + $this->p_a;

    }// Fin del constructor

    public function an_serv($fecha_i){
        list($ano,$mes,$dia) = explode("-",$this->fecha_i);
        $ano_diferencia  = date("Y") - $ano;
        $mes_diferencia = date("m") - $mes;
        $dia_diferencia   = date("d") - $dia;
        if ($dia_diferencia < 0 && $mes_diferencia < 0){
            $ano_diferencia--;
        }                
        return $ano_diferencia;
    }

    public function Guardar(){

        $db = DataBase::Conect();

        $sql1 = "insert into empleado (estatus, cedula, nombre, apellido, correo) values (:estatus, :cedula, :nombre, :apellido, :correo)";

        $query1 = $db->prepare($sql1);

        $query1->execute(array(":estatus" =>  $this->estatus,
                              ":cedula" =>  $this->cedula,
                              ":nombre" =>  $this->nombre,
                              ":apellido" => $this->apellido,
                              ":correo" =>  $this->correo));

        $resultado1 = $query1;

        $sql2 = "insert into fijo (cedula,a_s,s_m,p_a,n_s) values (:cedula,:a_s,:s_m,:p_a,:n_s)";

        $query2 = $db->prepare($sql2);

        $query2->execute(array(":cedula" => $this->cedula ,
                               ":a_s" => $this->a_s,
                               ":s_m" => $this->s_m,
                               ":p_a" => $this->p_a,
                               ":n_s" => $this->n_s ));
        $resultado2 = $query2;

        $query1->closeCursor();
        $query2->closeCursor();

        return $resultado1;
   }

}//Fin de la Clase Fijo
```

Comment: Hola Anonymous Programer, te damos la bienvenida al sitio. Completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre su funcionamiento y lee [ask] donde encontrarás consejos para escribir buenas preguntas y que sean mejor recibidas por la comunidad. Un saludo.

Comment: El error que recibes es porque al insertar en la base de datos estás dejando a null un campo que tiene una restricción de not null. Deberías agregar la estructura de la tabla empleado en tu base de datos para que podamos ver si el error puede estar por ahí.

Comment: Parece que estás pasando un valor nulo, revisa los datos que recibes y que quieres pasar a la base de datos no sean nulos

Answer (score 1):

Le estás pasando un argumento de fecha pero estás trabajando con una variable de la instancia:

```
public function an_serv($fecha_i){
    list($ano,$mes,$dia) = explode("-",$this->fecha_i);
    ....
}
```

Debiera en cambio ser:

```
public function an_serv($fecha_i){
    list($ano,$mes,$dia) = explode("-",$fecha_i);
    ....
}
```

O bien fijar el valor de `$this->fecha_i` en el constructor

Comment: ahora me da este error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function an_serv() in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\CS\Models\EmployeeModels.php:104 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\CS\Controller\Controller.php(33): Fijo->__construct('2017-10-27', 'Fijo', '25623441', 'Alexander', 'Cortez', 'alex_barrios321...', '1') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\HTML\CS\Models\EmployeeModels.php on line 104

Comment: habría que ver si acaso estás llamando `an_serv` como si fuera una función global en EmployeeModels